# Throwing exceptions in pimcore

Tags: php, zend-framework, pimcore

Does anyone know if there are 'pimcore-exceptions' or do I have to throw the Zend Framework- or PHP-exceptions?

I've scanned their GitHub-repository but found no hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a couple of pimcore-specific exceptions (take a look at pimcore/config/autoload-classmap.php):

- Pimcore\Tool\RestClient\Exception
- Pimcore\Image\Matrixcode\Renderer\Exception
- Pimcore\Image\Matrixcode\Qrcode\Exception
- Pimcore\Image\Matrixcode\Exception
- Pimcore\API\Plugin\Exception

For common use cases stick to the Zend exceptions, using plain PHP exceptions (and/or define your onw) where none seem appropriate.